# Write a file to dropbox in javascript from html form

Tags: javascript, forms

I saw that is possible to upload to dropbox directly with javascript following this example

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/writing-a-file-with-the-dropbox-javascript-sdk/

What I'd like to do is to create a text file containing the data from an html form and then submit it to dropbox. Suppose I have a form:

```
<form action="???" method="POST">
  <input name="field1" type="text" />
  <input name="field2" type="text" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

what should I write in the action field? How can i pass the variable "field1" and "field2" to the actual javascript, where the line of code that actually writes the file is :

```
client.writeFile('hello.txt', 'Hello, World!', function () {
    alert('File written!');
});
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Take a file input, read it using JavaScript and then pass the values of filename and the text of file. If you have any link for that.

Comment: Sorry @Bhansa I do not follow you here. Data input is in a form, how do you pass the data to a string which finally go into the write function?

Comment: give that input element an id and access it using javascript. `document.getElementById("id-that-you-gave").value`